# How to fix "imagePickerController" can't picker the photo?

Tags: swift, xcode

`instance method 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'` nearly matches optional requirement `'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'` of protocol `'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'`

I tried this suggest but still can't display the photo.Then I can choose the photo

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        classifier.text = "Analyzing Image..."
        guard let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
```

Make `'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'` private to silence this warning

Comment: Depending on your swift version, remove the definition, start rewriting it, let the autocompletion help you. For instance, in current Swift version, it's not `[String : Any]` anymore. It's `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`

Answer (score 1):

Change `String` to `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey`.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
```

See

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** 
Use the following Delegate methods to pick an image and also check if the user clicked cancel button.

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        {

        }

 }

 func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

 }
```